# An Error Was Encountered

Tags: templates

In the admin CP, I receive this error:
"This form has expired. Please refresh and try again."

This happens when I try to change a template, create one, or save anything to the site. Refreshing and trying again does nothing, my only solution is to switch browsers or clear browser caches, log in again, and try again which fixes the problem very temporarily. It happens every time I start working on the site again after being off of it, and it sometimes starts happening in the middle of working. Site is in development still, haven't even started editing channels yet.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Multi-site v 2.9.3

Comment: Is this an ExpressionEngine error message or is it your browser telling you that the forms has expired? What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

EE changed it's security specs from 2.8. If your are having difficulties with Codeigniter's CSRF protection on your local machine I would add this variable to your config.php file

`$config[‘disable_csrf_protection’] = “y”;`